# jQuery validate and tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-tabs

Hi i am using jQuery validate for my form validation.

The form is inside tabs.When i get an error i add an icon to the tab that error exist to be visual by the user

So far so good.

My problem is that after correct the error i can not remove the error in tab icon.
I was assuming that validator is accessible via success but its not

Assuming that the first tab (tab0) has 3 field for validation (field1,field2,field3)

Here is the full code

```
    $("form#Form1")
        .validate({
            invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {              
                //TAB 0
                if (validator.errorMap.field1 != "" && validator.errorMap.field2 != "" && validator.errorMap.field3 != "") {
                    if ($("#tabs>ul>li").eq(0).find("img").length == 0) {
                        $("#tabs>ul>li").eq(0).prepend("<img src=\"error.gif\">");
                    }
                }               
            },
            errorClass: "errorField",
            errorElement: "p",
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                var parent = element.parent();
                parent.addClass("error");
                error.prependTo( parent );
            },
//validator in not accessible via success
//so my code its not working
            success: function(element,validator) {
                var parent = element.parent();
                parent.removeClass("error");
                $(parent).children("p.errorField").remove();
                //TAB 0
                if (validator.errorMap.field1 == "" && validator.errorMap.field2 == "" && validator.errorMap.field2 == "") {
                    if ($("#tabs>ul>li").eq(0).find("img").length == 0) {
                        $("#tabs>ul>li").eq(0).find("img").remove();
                    }
                }   

           },   
            rules: {
                    field1: { required: true },
                    field2: { required: true },
                    field3: { required: true }      
                    }
    });
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Surely if the success method is called then all error icons can be hidden?

Comment: I don't know that this would matter, but looking at the docs, the success: callback takes only one parameter.

Comment: Thats not true.If you have 2 tabs and each tab has 3 field for validation i must hide the error icon only for the tab that errors are fixed.Success is called on each element that is in the rule option

Answer (score 2):

How about removing the icon from all tabs just before validating.

```
 $("form#Form1")
    .validate({
        //remove all icons here.
        //rest of your code
```

When the validation fails again it will replace the icon where necessary.

Comment: I want the icon remove the way the error in field remove, and i dont know any option of the validate that execute code before validate.I dont think that this is possibe.

Answer (score 1):

I realize it's been a few months, but I just had to handle this issue myself and I believe that I have come up with a good solution.

Rather than decorating the tab containing an error in the `invalidHandler`, instead use the `highlight` and `unhighlight` handlers to appropriately highlight or unhighlight the tab containing the invalid entry. Unlike `invalidHandler` which doesn't get called until a submission is attempted (or a manual call to validate it), `highlight` and `unhighlight` are called whenever an invalid field is processed- including onBlur.

```
jQuery('#Form').validate({
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        $('a[href=#' + $(element).parents('.ui-tabs-panel').attr('id') + ']').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        $('a[href=#' + $(element).parents('.ui-tabs-panel').attr('id') + ']').removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    }
});
```

In the code above for `highlight` and `unhighlight` I add and remove the appropriate error and valid classes from the invalid element (default behavior) and then I use a (double) selector to get any `<a />` that load that element's containing div and I add or remove the same classes to that tab link. This code assumes that the tab content is *not* loaded with AJAX and the links which load the div have an href to the div's anchor ID. If your tab link configuration differs you'll probably have to tweak the selector a little according to your needs.

---

#### Update

After testing this some more I have identified one pitfall, which may decrease the legitimacy of the solution. Namely, this will remove the error class from the tab link regardless of whether or not there are still invalid elements in that tab. The invalid elements still remain highlighted, but the tab loses its highlighting. I've been experimenting with viable workarounds to this issue and so far I have not found one. I'll update this if/when I do.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me.  I found that the #formID in the first selector of the else clause speeds up the code on busy forms.

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(formID);
if ($(formID).valid()) {
    ...
    ...
}
else {
    $("#formID  #tabID").tabs("select", $("#formID .input-validation-error")
        .closest(".ui-tabs-panel").get(0).id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fighting with the same problem, but have given up too... IMHO the real blocker is that jQuery validate has no `onBeforeValidate` callback. This would allow you to remove all error icons before the validation begins and then let validate() re-assign them if necessary.

Comment: Dear Franz i have solve the problem using the original code posted but its not that "dynamic" because for each tab i have to write extra controls

Comment: I found out that it's impossible to do a "live" update of all tab errors. The problem: when the user tries to correct an invalid form field, ONLY its value is passed to the validate plugin and its callback machinery ==> you don't get the status of the other fields. Finally I resorted to invalidHandler() because it only gets called when the user wants to submit and thus captures the complete error status of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source it seems like all he does when figuring out what to remove when a field becomes valid is look for elements of the appropriate type with the right CSS class. By default that's <label /> and "error". So I wrote some extra code in my custom errorPlacement function to stick an extra label in the tab header when a field is invalid, and as long as I created it correctly he removed it for me as soon as the field is valid:

```
 errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                $(error).appendTo($(element).closest('.form-item').find('.form-label-error'));
                var tabLabel = $("<label style='position: absolute; '/>")
                .attr("for", element.attr('id'))
                .addClass("error")
                .html("*");

                $('a[href="#' + $(element).closest('.ui-tabs-panel').attr("id") + '"] .tab-errors').append(tabLabel);
                resizeDialog($('#popup-container'));
            }
```

Note that I made the position of the label absolute, so that they would just sit on top of each other, to the user there's no difference between a stack of 10 and just one. The correct tab to mark is figured out just by tracing the DOM tree (thanks Nathan Taylor!), presumably if it's not in a tab the selector should fail. My tab definitions look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#protocol-settings">Protocol<div style="display: inline-block; width:5px; height:10px; margin-left: 2px;" class="tab-errors"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#auth-settings">Authentication<div style="display: inline-block; width:5px; height:10px; margin-left: 2px;" class="tab-errors"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#trust-settings">Certificates<div style="display: inline-block; width:5px; height:10px; margin-left: 2px;" class="tab-errors"></div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution I think is pretty clean and user-friendly, simple focus the tab with the next error, this works as long as your inputs get the class input-validation-error when there's an error, but you can change the code to look for anything, here's the function:

```
function FocusTabWithErrors(tabPanelName) {
    var tabpanel = $(tabPanelName);
    var tabs = tabpanel.children('div').toArray();
    var tabNames = Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        tabNames[i] = "#" + tabs[i].id;
    }
    tabpanel.find(":input").each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('input-validation-error')) { 
            for (var z = 0; z < tabNames.length; z++) {
                if ($(tabNames[z]).find($(this)).length)
                    tabpanel.tabs("select", z);
            }
            return false; // ends each
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

Then you just bind to the form's submit event:

```
    $('#myForm').submit(function () {
        FocusTabWithErrors('#tabPanel');
    });
```

Let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the **validator** instance by calling [validate()](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) method **without passing any options** on the **jquery selector** where the validator was **configured earlier**. Also note that the success callback receives **a single parameter pointing to the DOM label** that was created for the invalid input. So, your success callback should look like following and work as expected.

```
success: function(label) {
    var parent = label.parent(); // Or any other logic to find the parent container
    parent.removeClass("error");
    $(parent).children("p.errorField").remove();
    validator = $("form#Form1").validate(); 
    // not sure, but $(this).validate() should also return validator

    //TAB 0
    if (validator.errorMap.field1 == "" && validator.errorMap.field2 == "" && validator.errorMap.field2 == "") {
        if ($("#tabs>ul>li").eq(0).find("img").length == 0) {
            $("#tabs>ul>li").eq(0).find("img").remove();
        }
    }   
}
```